# Execute TCL on windows XP

Tags: tcl

I installed `tcl803.exe` on my `windows XP` Operating System and my `TCL` path is `C:\Tcl`. Now I am unable to execute the TCL script on windows XP operating system. Please help me. Here I am very new. Please tell me each and every steps. Here is my TCL script. I write in a notepad and save it as `a.tcl` extension.

```
set x 50
set y 400
puts stdout "$x+$y=[expr {$x+$y}]"
puts stdout "-The addition of two variables $x and $y is [expr $x+$y]"
```

Comment: `Now i am unable to execute the TCL script on windows XP operating system.` if you don't tell people what happened when you tried you reduce the chances of them being able to help you.

Comment: Actually what i did, now i am writing in very details. Please .. i installed the tcl803.exe on my windows XP Operating System and my path is C:\Tcl. So i go to dos prompt: C:\Tcl and try to execute our .tcl extension scripts. so i wrote the command on dos prompt like: C:\Tcl>ddd.tcl   so it is saying that ddd.tcl is not a recognised as an external or internal command. and my file ddd.tcl is in the same folder i.e. C:\Tcl

Comment: Here i also don't know the windows TCL compiler. Please tell me how to compile on windows XP operating system.

Comment: And also tell me " Is it possible to run tcl scripts on windows Xp Operating system. Please tell me requirements.

Comment: Tcl803.exe sounds like it is at least 10 years old. Maybe try to start with something like the active state Tcl distribution instead?

Comment: @schlenk: +1 for getting to the root of the problem

Comment: thanks for suggestion. Now i downloaded Active state Tcl and it is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Tcl files aren't compiled, they're scripts that require they be handed to a Tcl interpreter to run. You have two  primary options on Windows:

1. Run the tcl interpreter with the script as an argument:

   `tclsh.exe ddd.tcl`
2. Associate `.tcl` files with the `tclsh` (or wish) interpreters. I don't recall how to do this offhand, but it's similar to associate `.doc` items with Word... When you double click on the `.tcl` file it calls the executable (Tcl) and gives it the name of the `.tcl` file you clicked on.

Note: You can "compile" tcl code into an executable (tclkit, starkit), but you probably aren't at a point where you'd be comfortable doing so.

Comment: Checking one of the answers as "the answer" if it solved your problem is generally considered the correct thing to do. Whether mine or glenn's (both are correct and, it appears, helpful) is up to you, but you should choose one.

Answer (score 5):

Do this at a DOS prompt:

```
assoc .tcl=TclScript
ftype TclScript=c:\Tcl\tclsh.exe %1 %*
```

However, it would be much easier for you to install [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) -- that install process will manage the file associations for you.